# How do I delete a page in a Word 2007 document?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2007

I would like to know how to delete an entire page in Word 2007. I cannot select any text inside the page. Thanks.

Comment: We need you to provide more details on the reason you cannot select the contents on the page delete said content.

Comment: See Word MVP Suzanne Barnhill's page on deleting blank pages. http://wordfaqs.ssbarnhill.com/BlankPage.htm

Answer (score 3):

From the [Microsoft Office support forums](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Add-or-delete-a-page-174fedd3-b4e5-42e4-a4d0-5e25127a1404):

> **Delete a page**
>
> You can delete a blank page in a Word document, including a blank page
>   that occurs at the end of the document, by deleting page breaks. You
>   can also combine two pages by deleting the page break between them.
>
> **Delete a blank page**
>
> Make sure that you're in Draft view (on the View menu in the status
>   bar, click Draft). If nonprinting characters, such as paragraph
>   markers (¶), are not visible, on Home, in the Paragraph group, click
>   Show/Hide  Paragraph mark.
>
> To delete a blank page, select the page break at the end of the page,
>   and then press DELETE.
>
> **Delete a single page of content**
>
> You can select and delete a single page of content anywhere in your
>   document.
>
> Place your cursor anywhere in the page of content that you want to
>   delete.
>
> On the Home tab, in the Find group, click the arrow next to Find, and
>   then click Go To.
>
> Word Ribbon Image
>
> Type \page and then click Go To.
>
> The content of the page is selected.
>
> Click Close, and then press DELETE.
>
> **Delete a blank page at the end of a document**
>
> Make sure that you're in Draft view (on the View menu in the status
>   bar, click Draft). If nonprinting characters, such as paragraph
>   markers (¶), are not visible, on Home, in the Paragraph group, click
>   Show/Hide  Paragraph mark.
>
> To delete a blank page at the end of the document, select the page
>   break or any paragraph markers (¶) at the end of the document, and
>   then press DELETE.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: Type some text in that blank page

Step 2: Then Select those text along with last word/character from the previous page

Step 3: Press the Delete button in the keyboard

Step 4: The blank page has been deleted. Now type the already deleted text in the previous page.

Answer (score 0):

-You can try to delete it from previous page,
-or maybe your file is protected so you need to enable it to edit
- or you can try to active show paragraph marks on home tab to show the pilcrow and delete it

Answer (score 0):

***How To Delete A Blank Page Ms Word 2007***

**Select A Blank Page To Delete**

[image: screenshot]

**Then Hit Delete A Few Moments Till The Page Gets Deleted**

[image: screenshot]